# window.localStorage.getItem() и window.sessionStorage.getItem() возвращают null

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Здраствуйте, только начинаю учить js

`window.localStorage.getItem()` и `window.sessionStorage.getItem()` возвращают `null` при том, что если зайти в application в хроме значения присутствуют.

```js
let startBtn = document.getElementById("startBtn")
startBtn.onclick = game;
document.getElementById('clearBR').addEventListener('click', ClearBestResult)
document.getElementById('clearBRforAllTime').addEventListener('click', ClearBestResultForAllTime)
let result
function game() {
   let count = 0
   const nickname = document.getElementById("nickname").value
   document.getElementById('click').addEventListener('click', clickCount)
   let arr = []
   function clickCount() {
      count++
      arr.push(count)
   }
   try {
      if (nickname === "") throw new Error()
   } catch (e) {
      alert('nickname is empty')
   }
   finally {
      setTimeout(function () {
         result = arr.length
         alert(`You clicked ${result} times`)
         if (sessionStorage.getItem, (nickname, result) < result || sessionStorage.getItem, (nickname, result) === undefined) {
            sessionStorage.clear()
            sessionStorage.setItem(nickname, result.toString())
         } else if (result > localStorage.getItem, (nickname, result) || localStorage.getItem === undefined) {
            localStorage.clear()
            localStorage.setItem(nickname, result.toString())
         }
         count = 0
         arr.splice(0, arr.length);
      }, 5000);
   }
   document.getElementById('BRforAllTime').addEventListener('click', bestForAllTimes)
   document.getElementById('BR').addEventListener('click', bestResult)
   function bestForAllTimes() {
      alert(`Best result for the whole time is: ${localStorage.getItem(result)} by ${localStorage.getItem("nickname")}`)
   }
   function bestResult() {
      alert(`Best result is ${window.sessionStorage.getItem(result)}`)
   }
   console.log(sessionStorage.getItem(result)) // null
   console.log(localStorage.getItem(result)) //null
}
function ClearBestResult() {
   window.sessionStorage.clear()
   alert('Best result is cleared')
}
function ClearBestResultForAllTime() {
   localStorage.clear()
   alert('Best result for the whole time is cleared')
}
```

Comment: Как быстро вы заходите в `application` за 5 секунд или дольше?)

Comment: во вкладку приложение в панели розроботчика)

Comment: Я знаю где это) Я спрашиваю как быстро вы успеваете зайти в эту вкладку?) Вопрос не для издевательства я справшиваю. Дело в том что ваши `console.log` сработают сразу, ещё до   `setTimeout` и потому будут показывать `null`, а вот то что внутри `setTimeout` через 5 секунд. Потому и спросил как быстро вы смотрите в свою вкладку?)

Comment: Это функция, которая находиться во внутри другой функции. Программа считает клики которые я успел нажать за 5  секунд. ’’’null’’’ я получаю сразу после выполнение программы

Comment: `console.log(window.localStorage.getItem(result))` и `console.log(window.sessionStorage.getItem(result))` отработают сразу, не дожидаясь 5-ти секунд и потому ваш хранилища на данном этапе будут пустыми

Comment: Если нетрудно можете глянуть скриншот кода ?

Comment: https://ibb.co/cFpGxwn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout` запустит функцию переданную первым параметром, через указанное кол-во миллисекунд вторым параметром, после инициализации этого участка кода JS "читает" дальше, там `console.info()` с получение значение по ключу из хранилища, они вернут `undefined` т.к. их нет.

Через 5 секунд запускается функция.
Там через пару строк снова запрашиваем значение у сессионного хранилища - ответ должен быть `undefined`, ибо по коду нигде назначений не было, но вы указали что возвращается `null`, допустим..

Далее проверка, которая вернёт `true`, ибо одно из условий проходит (второе - `sessionStorage.getItem(nickname, result) === undefined`).

Окей, там очищаем сессию, причём всю.. Допустим.
Далее создаём ключ с новым значение по переменным.

Переходим на вторую проверку.. вернёт `false`, ещё и ... `localStorage.getItem,false` это что вообще?
Она пролетает, ибо по коду не вижу назначения в локальное хранилище.

---

Решения два:

1. Обдумать и сформулировать код, ну и переписать всё заного.
2. Докинуть в вопрос недостающую часть кода, ибо что-то мне подсказывает, что вы что-то упустили. Если не так, то остаётся только первый вариант решения.

---

### Дополнение ответа

В условиях ошибки

```
if(sessionStorage.getItem, (nickname, result) < result || sessionStorage.getItem, (nickname, result) === undefined) {
  sessionStorage.clear()
  sessionStorage.setItem(nickname, result.toString())
} else if (result > localStorage.getItem, (nickname, result) || localStorage.getItem === undefined) {
  localStorage.clear()
  localStorage.setItem(nickname, result.toString())
}
```

должно быть [`.getItem(nickname)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) который в свою очередь вернёт строку, чтобы сравнить её с `result`, которая судя по всему имеет числовой тип, нужно строку вовращаемого перевести в число.

Например так - [`Number(sessionStorage.getItem(nickname))`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) `< result`.

---

В некоторых местах вы запрашиваете `.getItem('nickname')`, но судя по коду вы хотите найти ключ по переменной, следовательно кавычки нужно убрать.

В целом больше ошибок не вижу, кроме тех, что описал выше до дополнения ответа.

---

Есть недочёт, как по мне.

Метод [`.clear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Storage/clear) удалить **все** записи в хранилище, следовательно результаты **всех** игроков удалятся.

Может всё же лучше удалять "текущего" игрока, через [`.removeItem(nickname)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem)?

Comment: Если можете глянуть на скриншот.https://ibb.co/cFpGxwn

Comment: Вижу много ошибок в коде, либо VSC так отображает (не пользуюсь им, точно сказать не могу).. Код лучше скидывать кодом в вопрос.

Comment: @user497202, дополнил ответ, посмотрите

Comment: Спасибо, все отлично работает